# convert a huge Excel table to a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have a database shown in the picture, which is copied from an excel table. (the link of picture coz i can't add it here due to low reputation:   https://ibb.co/iQhks6)

[image]

I want to program excel to make a graph with y-axis as aircraft registration numbers and x-axis is time, and should have bars around time when it is on the ground. For example, A-1234 should have a bar from 1850 to 2300, 0600 to 0700, 1200 to 1230.

If the bars can have colours representing the airport an aircraft is parking at, it will be great.

So my question is, how to program that? or are there any other free software that can generate that kind of graph with this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved without any programming at all, using careful data layout and an Excel stacked horizontal chart. The screenshot shows a starting point.

[image]

The data is alternating columns for time in the air and time on the ground. Select the data and create a stacked horizontal chart, then select each air time series in turn and format it to have no fill color.